This statement is false right? Susanna Epp Exercise Set 3.3, Question 19
Link to Question
Exist real number X, such that for every real number Y,X+Y = 0

This statement should be false right? The book did not tell us to show whether it is false or true. In my reading, the question is saying there is a real number x such that when x is added together with any real number y, then it will equal to 0. To me this is untrue because I can find a value for y that will prove this false.
I am still starting out and I  want to confirm that I don't have an issue when it comes to interpreting statements like this.
Any help would be appreaciated. Cheers

$X+(1-X)=1 \neq 0$.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You're correct with your interpretation.
To prove it false, suppose there is such an $x$, and we'll find a contradiction. If there is such an $X$, then
$$
X+1 = X+2 = 0
$$
in particular. (Take $Y=1$ and $Y=2$.) But then $1=2$, a contradiction.
